# How to keep pageControl in place while scrolling in a UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

I've pinned my UIPageControl at the bottom of the collection view controller using this function in viewDidLoad..

```
 func setUpViewsAndConstraints(){
    collectionView.addSubview(pageControl)
    collectionView.bringSubviewToFront(pageControl)



    pageControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    pageControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true


}
```

but when I scroll through the cells (horizontally) the pageControl stays under the first cell and is left behind when I move on to the next cell...

I thought that just cells moved when scrolling and collectionView stay in place but it seems it's not the case, or I'm doing something wrong..

what am I missing here?
thank you in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to keep the pageControl under the collectionView and not inside, as I can see you are adding a bottomAnchor at your pageControl to the same bottom of the collectionView; try to keep them separately and add a top constraint to your pageControl to the bottom of collectionView and add a centralAnchor to your ViewController

```
pageControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
pageControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

And maybe a bottom constraint to your view

```
pageControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Obviously for this case you should have a UIViewController parent with a UICollectionView and a pageControl as children